# How do I install texlive-latex-extra on Windows

Tags: tlmgr, texlive-2021

I am new to TeX/LaTeX. First I install the full texlive.iso which is around `4.1GB`. I was guessing that include the `texlive-latex-extra` but no. Then I tried to install it manually,

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> tlmgr install texlive-latex-extra
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package texlive-latex-extra not present in repository.
tlmgr.pl: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Google search gives solution for linux distro not for Windows OS.

Comment: `texlive-latex-extra` isn't a TeX Live package I know of: are you mixing it up with say a Linux distro's packaging of TeX Live?

Comment: Is there no way to install it in Windows? @Joseph Wright♦

Comment: Like I said, that sounds like a Linux package to me: Linux distros tend to split up TeX Live into pre-defined bundles of their own making. If you've installed a full TeX Live using the 'vanilla' installer from TUG, you'll have _everything_. Perhaps you could say what's not working in your documents?

Comment: Actually I want to use Xournalpp++ software which can't render latex formula. I found this [issue](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/issues/2227) which say installing `texlive-latex-extra` resolve the problem.

Comment: That's a Xournal++ issue and (I suspect) about configuration

Comment: I have the same question but for macOS. I know I'm missing wrapfig.sty, and the internet tells me I need textlive-latex-extra, but I installed `basictex` with brew and I only have `tlmgr`.